# My answer always shows up as zero?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making a jelly bean guesser. My teacher gave us a base case with length as 1.93 cm, diameter as 1.39 cm, and jar size volume as 500. The answer should be 180. I do not get any errors on my code yet my answer shoes up as zero when it should be 180. Please help!

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText jellyBeanLength, jellyBeanDiameter, jarSizeVolume;
    double jellybeantall, jellybeanfat, jellybeanspace, volumeOfOneJellyBean, volumeofBeans;
    final double loadFactor = .702; //worked for class jelly bean. Got the same answer on board if jar size was 500, length was 1.93 and diameter was 1.39.
    TextView answer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        jellyBeanLength = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.length);
        jellyBeanDiameter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.diameter);
        jarSizeVolume = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jarsize);
        answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
        Button solveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);


        solveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                volumeOfOneJellyBean = (3.14159265359 / 6) * (jellybeanfat * jellybeanfat) * (jellybeantall);
                volumeofBeans = (jellybeanspace * loadFactor) / volumeOfOneJellyBean;
                int jellyGuess = (int) (volumeofBeans);
                answer.setText("My guess is " + jellyGuess + " Jelly Beans");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jellybeanspace is never assigned.  So its 0.  THat makes volumeOfBeans 0.

Comment: also jellybeanfat

Comment: Also jellybeantall